# Returning all records and displays only 1 record only when there is more than 1 of the same record

Tags: php, mysql

I have an SQL statement that displays all the record of a participants that filters from a contactperson's id.

```
<?php
 query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM participants WHERE contactperson = '$session_id'");

while($cys_row = mysql_fetch_array($cys_query)){
 returns all the records of the participants
}
?>
```

I found a way of displaying the participants with more than 1 record on the same contactperson by adding a `HAVING` clause on my SQL statement.

```
<?php
 query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM participants HAVING Count(*)");


while($cys_row = mysql_fetch_array($cys_query)){
 returns all the records of the participants with more than 1 of the same information
}
?>
```

What I need to achieve is that, I want to select all the participants on that contactperson but select only one record if the record of the same participant is more than 1. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

Use the [DISTINCT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/distinct-optimization.html) clause in MySQL:

```
query = mysqli_query("SELECT DISTINCT(contactperson) AS contactperson, colum2, colum3 FROM participants WHERE contactperson = '$session_id'");
```

Here, you should use [mysqli_query()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php), as mysql_query is deprecated.

Comment: Also, if there's *any* chance that `$session_id` comes from the client, use bound parameters. That should be obvious, but hey, OP *is* using mysql_query...

Comment: Yeah.. That's why I am advising him to use mysqli_query...because mysql_query is not recommended now..and anyway mysql_query() will work in the same way. @user866762